# How can I break a line in playwright for python

Tags: python, textarea, playwright

How can I break a line in playwright for python？
I want to enter a line break in the textarea.

I have already tried the below but it did not work.

```
page.fill('text=First Name', 'A\nB\nC');
```

Comment: Have you tried using triple quotes? `"""`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, is your element maybe no `textarea` or prevents new lines with a custom onChange handler in e.g. React?

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    for browser_type in [p.chromium, p.firefox, p.webkit]:
        browser = browser_type.launch()
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.set_content("""<textarea id="foobar"></textarea>""")
        page.fill("#foobar", "foo\nbar")
        page.screenshot(path="example.png")
        browser.close()
```